# How could I get view of one fragment while add this fragment to an Activity

Tags: android, view, android-activity, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I have one FragmentActivity and a Fragment, well, now I want to add this fragment to the Activity programmatically, and I also want to update value of one TextView. but I keep getting NullPointException.
Need some help here... :(

this is my code:

```
public class NewsDetailsFragment extends Fragment {

private View _currentview = null;

public View getCurrentView() {
    return _currentview;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    _currentview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newsdetails_layout, container,
            false);

    Button b = (Button) _currentview.findViewById(R.id.btnReplace);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction();
            if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                transaction.replace(R.id.landscapeLayout,
                        new ReplacementFragment(), "replace");
            } else {
                transaction.replace(R.id.newsdetailsPortrait,
                        new ReplacementFragment(), "replace");
            }
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });

    return _currentview;
}

public void setNewsContent(String content) {
    TextView lblNewsContent = (TextView) getView().findViewById(
            R.id.lblNewsContent);
    lblNewsContent.setText(content);
    lblNewsContent.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
}
```

}

This is the FragmentActivity:

```
public class NewsDetailsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.newsdetailsactivity_layout);

    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        finish();
        return;
    }

    // setContentView(R.layout.newsdetails_layout);
    NewsDetailsFragment detailsFragment = new NewsDetailsFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.newsdetailsPortrait, detailsFragment,
            "newsdatails");

    String newString = getIntent().getStringExtra("news");
    if (null != newString) {

        TextView t = (TextView) detailsFragment.getView().findViewById(
                R.id.lblNewsContent);
        t.setText(newString);
        t.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
    }

    transaction.commit();

}
```

}

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: It looks like you're using the transaction.add method using a tag. Normally, I use this when adding fragments to an activity without a contentview. So my first guess would be that you're trying to add the fragment to a ViewGroup in your newsdetailsactivity_layout, but using the wrong add method for this. Maybe use add(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment) instead? Anyway, could you add your activity layout file? Makes it easier to see what you're trying to achieve. ;)

Comment: You can't access the fragment's view at that point because it isn't built yet. Use a `Bundle` and pass the `newString` in it to the `NewsDetailsFragment` instance. Then, in the fragment you'd use `getArguments()` to get the `Bundle` and string and set the text on the `TextView`.

Comment: Thanks, both of you, I finally fix this issue by Luksprog's instruction. I also tried to do the "set TextView" thing in onStart(), but it doesn't work neither; I know I don't understand life cycle of Activity/FragmentActivity very well, but I think onStart means the "View" could be visible to users, right? why I still cannot access its view here? still get NullPointException. :(